# Open new Page according to clicked <td> which is also coming from MySql in JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp

I'm Making Localhost MailServer, I have done inbox sentbox and all mail pages, but i stuck in **How To Open an Email According to clicked**  
Firstly i Clear you that i have a database name mailbox where all the Records are Stored. i want to open that Mail according to click on subject

```
{

    <table>



                <th>Sender ID</th>
               <th style="text-align: center">Subject</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th>





           <% 
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/srk",
            "root", "root");


            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset = 
                statement.executeQuery("select senderID,subject,date,time from mailbox where senderID = '" +session.getAttribute("userid") + "' or receiverID = '" +session.getAttribute("userid") + "'") ; 
 while(resultset.next()){
        %>





           <tr>


               <td><b> <%= resultset.getString(1) %></b> </td>

               <td style="text-align:center"><a href=""> <%= resultset.getString(2) %>&nbsp;</a> </td>

               <td> <%= resultset.getDate(3) %>&nbsp; </td>

                 <td> <%= resultset.getTime(4) %> </td>

           </tr>
           <% } %>
       </table>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be specific as in, where you have to go on clicking the subject. 
Now,

```
<td style="text-align:center"><a href=""> <%= resultset.getString(2) %>&nbsp;</a> </td>
```

refers to nowhere as href is empty. If you have to go to a specific jsp, just mention it there in the href. Do comment if there is anything else to add to the answer.